# find rows not following by the same values in 3 columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named `raw_data` with the following data

[image]

as You can see `id` 1 and 2 share the same values in field `desa`, `kecamatan` and `kabupaten`,  also `id` 3,4,5. 
So basically I want to select all rows that is not followed by the same previous values. expected result would be:

[image]

I know it's easy to do this in any programming languages such as `PHP`, but I need this in postgresql. is this doable? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming higher id denotes latest row, if a row with same all three columns is present not together and you don't want to filter it out as it doesn't have same values as previous row (order by id or created_date), then you can make use of analytic `lag()` function:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        case 
            when desa = lag(desa) over (order by id)
            and kecamatan = lag(kecamatan) over (order by id)
            and kabupaten = lag(kabupaten) over (order by id)
            then 0 else 1
        end flag
    from your_table t
) t where flag = 1;
```

Comment: almost perfect. notice, `palasari` appear twice in the result and that's what i expected, because the second occurance of `palasari` was preceded by `cipadung`.

Comment: Makes sense. @Dariel can you try the third solution?

Comment: yes your 3rd solution works like charm. thanks a lot. it's a complex query and out of my knowledge :D

Comment: @Dariel Not really. Simple `case` and `lag`. Just lookup these two on the internet.